# Bottom-aligned columns in xltabular

Tags: vertical-alignment, longtable, xltabular

I'm trying to make some bottom-aligned columns in `xltabular` but it doesn't seem to work for some reason. Preferably, I would have them function like l/c/r (ie. calculate the width automatically so I don't have to iterate to a good one). Also, I would like the `\dotfill`s to extend to the numbers in the third row.

What am I doing wrong?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\rbraced[2]{%
    $\genfrac{}{\rbrace}{0pt}{}{\textrm{#1}}{\textrm{#2}}$%
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\scriptsize
%\newcolumntype{B}{>{\begin{minipage}[t][\height][b]{\width}}X<{\end{minipage}}}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}b{.1\linewidth}}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{r X B l B}
    A. & Lundevang: & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Herredsbogen 1695} \\
    & I Kattegiere Aas, fra Øst til Vest, mellem Landeveien og Markskjellet, %
har Hendrich Thiszen i Leÿe og Brug af Præsten i Søeborg 2~Agre, %
tilsammen 9.042½ med Enge, 4.906, \dotfill & 13.948½ & 2 Attebechs Agre & .2.. Bÿg \\
    B. & Wougelsvang: & & Slaavangen \\
    & I Laehøÿs Aas, mellem Steenveldegjærde og Steenvelde-Aas, S. og N. %
6 agre, tilsammen \dotfill & 25.526¼ & Aasz Ager & .7½.. Bÿg \\
    C. & Bakkevang: & & Tverstivang & \\
    & I Grønnels Aas, S. och N., mellem Brandtebierg Aas og Fellestette-Aas
1 Ager \rbraced{19½ Al.}{17½ --} bred, 287 Al. lang \dotfill & 5.309½ & Græsveis Aas & .2.. Bÿg \\
    & I Sand-Aasen, Ø. och V., med Østersiden til Stenvelde-Giered
og med Vesterenden til Hÿrebacks Aas, 2 Agre \dotfill & 5.101½ & Sÿllen? & .2.. Bÿg \\
    & I Hÿrebacke-Aas, S. och N., ml. Sandaasen og Gasze-Aas
2 Agre, ½ Skp. Sæd i hver, \dotfill & 6.451½ & Hÿrdestÿkket & \rdelim\rbrace{5}{3mm} \multirow{5}{*}{.2.. Havre} \\
    & I Store Gasze Aas, Ø. och V., imll. Steenvelde-gierde og Udleg%
get, 1 Ager, 2 Otting Sæd, \rbraced{23 Al.}{16½ --} br., 271 Al. l. \dotfill & 5.352¼ & Ræddet? & \\
    & I Troldhøÿs Aas, Ø. och V., ml. Trolhøÿsgierde og Brandte%
bierg-Aas, 3 Agre, tilsammen \dotfill & 15.177⅛ & Troldaasager & .10.. Bÿg \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    & & 37.372⅞ & & .23½.. \\
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

How it currently looks:
[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

If above table is what you looking for, than you only before:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{r X  r l B}
```

need to add add:

```
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
```

**Addendum:**
Complete MWE, which also consider your comment (for the last column).:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, xltabular}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\rbraced[2]{%
    $\genfrac{}{\rbrace}{0pt}{}{\textrm{#1}}{\textrm{#2}}$%
}

\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.1\linewidth}}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{b{#1}}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{r X  r p{.15\linewidth} B}
A.  & Lundevang: & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Herredsbogen 1695}  \\
    & I Kattegiere Aas, fra Øst til Vest, mellem Landeveien og Markskjellet, har Hendrich Thiszen i Leÿe og Brug af Præsten i Søeborg 2~Agre, tilsammen 9.042½ med Enge, 4.906, \dotfill & 13.948½ 
        & \multirow[t]{-3}{=}{2 Attebechs Agre} & \multirow[t]{-3}{=}{.2.. Bÿg}     \\
    \addlinespace
B. & Wougelsvang: & & Slaavangen \\
    & I Laehøÿs Aas, mellem Steenveldegjærde og Steenvelde-Aas, S. og N. %
6 agre, tilsammen \dotfill & 25.526¼ 
        & \multirow[t]{-2}{=}{Aasz Ager}        & \multirow[t]{-2}{=}{.7½.. Bÿg}    \\
    \addlinespace
C. & Bakkevang: & & Tverstivang & \\
    & I Grønnels Aas, S. och N., mellem Brandtebierg Aas og Fellestette-Aas
1 Ager \rbraced{19½ Al.}{17½ --} bred, 287 Al. lang \dotfill  & 5.309½ 
        & \multirow[t]{-2}{=}{Græsveis Aas}     & \multirow[t]{-2}{=}{.2.. Bÿg} \\
    \addlinespace
    & I Sand-Aasen, Ø. och V., med Østersiden til Stenvelde-Giered
og med Vesterenden til Hÿrebacks Aas, 2 Agre \dotfill   & 5.101½ 
    & \multirow[t]{-2}{=}{Sÿllen?}         & \multirow[t]{-2}{=}{.2.. Bÿg}      \\
    \addlinespace
    & I Hÿrebacke-Aas, S. och N., ml. Sandaasen og Gasze-Aas
2 Agre, ½ Skp. Sæd i hver, \dotfill & 6.451½ 
    & Hÿrdestÿkket  & \rdelim\rbrace{5}{3mm} \multirow{5}{*}{.2.. Havre}        \\
    & I Store Gasze Aas, Ø. och V., imll. Steenvelde-gierde og Udleg%
get, 1 Ager, 2 Otting Sæd, \rbraced{23 Al.}{16½ --} br., 271 Al. l. \dotfill & 5.352¼ 
    & Ræddet? &     \\
    & I Troldhøÿs Aas, Ø. och V., ml. Trolhøÿsgierde og Brandte%
bierg-Aas, 3 Agre, tilsammen \dotfill & 15.177⅛ 
        & Troldaasager & .10.. Bÿg \\
    \cmidrule{3-5}
    & & 37.372⅞ & & .23½.. \\
\end{xltabular}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is almost correct. I would like the 4th column to remain top-aligned, is that possible?

Comment: Only 4th? The 5th should stay bottom aligned? This is not possible to do "automatically". You will need to tweak each cell manually.

Comment: Ok thanks again

Comment: @meide, I will show asap one way for the last column.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks!